# Passing Data from Datastore to http.Writer

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I was recently introduced to the wonders of the language known as **go**. I set myself a task of writing a RESTful API using GoLang and Google's Datastore. I am able to retrieve data from Datastore and Print it to the console using `fmt.Println` however the issue comes into play when I try to use the data from Datastore and pass it to the **http.Handler**.

I was wondering if someone could inform me of where I am going wrong or even point me in the right direction.

Here is what I have done so far

```
 package main

 import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "net/http"
 // "encoding/json"
    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
 )

 type Item struct {
      Id       string   `datastore:"id"`
      Name     string   `datastore:"title"`
      View     int      `datastore:"views"`
      Brand    string   `datastore:"brand"`
      id    int64   // interger from "Name/ID" fild in datastore entities list
 }

 func main() {
     http.HandleFunc("/", ListTasks)
     http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
 }

 //func ListTasks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) ([]*Item, error)     {
func ListTasks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-client")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var tasks []*Item

    query := datastore.NewQuery("my-query")
    keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, query, &tasks)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for i, key := range keys {
        tasks[i].id = key.ID
    }

    return tasks, nil
}
```

I've also looked into http Wrappers, but I'm unaware if using a wrapper is 100% necessary or if I'm just adding more to my plate.

Comment: You need to [stringify it to json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) and then send it to the `ResponseWriter`. (Or in a single step if you use the [`Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewEncoder))

Comment: You need to encode `tasks` to some data format and write that data to the response writer `w`.  What data format do you want to use?

Comment: Thank you @tkausl and ThunderCat for your help, it is greatly appreciated! If only I knew all I had to do was encode... My issue would've been resolved weeks ago, so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the `return tasks, nil` as it appeared to be unnecessary, modified the `return, nil err` to `log.Fatalln(nil, err)` and also encoded `tasks` as instructed by @ThunderCat and @tkausl. My issue has been resolved, thank you.

Here is my working code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
)

type Item struct {
    Id      string  `datastore:"id"`
    Name    string  `datastore:"title"`
    View    int     `datastore:"views"`
    Brand   string  `datastore:"brand"`
    id  int64   // interger from "Name/ID" fild in datastore entities list
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ListTasks)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func ListTasks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-client")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var tasks []*Item

    query := datastore.NewQuery("my-query")
    keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, query, &tasks)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(nil, err)
    }
    for i, key := range keys {
        tasks[i].id = key.ID
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tasks)
//  return tasks, nil
}
```

It now returns `[{"Id":"24X660","Name":"Fiesta","View":129,"Brand":"Ford"}]`

Also thank you to @static_cast for correcting my formatting errors.

Comment: Killing the server because of an error fetching data from the datastore is not a good idea.  Log the error and return status 500.